# Chrome font rendering artifacts

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, rendering

When I'm scrolling page and header become "position: fixed" there is some font rendering issue.

font bug

[image: 1]

Properties like

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

and

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

don't help. Also I've tried to reset Chrome flags.

Comment: I've noticed a font-rendering change with Chrome v108 (specifically antialiasing now looks that same on FF and Chrome where before Chrome rendered thinner letters). Maybe check your Chrome version and see if your issue is related.